# where go gems installed by rails command when i create a specified gemset later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundle, rvmrc

i generate my app with  `rails new app` and then i go to the home directory of my app like this : `cd app`, and i create a **.rvmrc** file to specify the gemset to use with this project and there will go all my gems instead of **default gemset** *created by rvm*.

but the first time when i create my app, and before creating my gemset (with .rvmrc file ) for this project, rails run automatically bundle install wich means that all gems installed by rails command are in **default gemset** !!!

i find this confusing , can someone explain that to me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the gemset before you create the rails app if you want:

```
rvm gemset create new_gemset_name
```

Then BEFORE you create the app w/ rails, run:

```
rvm use @new_gemset_name
```

That way when you run "rails create" the gems will be installed in the new gemset you just created.  Afterward you can create a .rvmrc file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting:

```
--skip-bundle
```

to your `~/.railsrc` file, you will edit Gemfile and run `bundle install` manually anyway.